# OpenCV Python Sample Error

Tags: python, opencv, sample

I'm trying to run one of the samples included in opencv: find_obj.py.
OpenCV version: 2.4
OS: ArchLinx

There is an error at the function:

```
flann = cv2.flann_Index(desc2, flann_params)
```

The error is:

```
File "find_obj2.py", line 27, in match_flann
    flann = cv2.flann_Index(desc2, flann_params)
TypeError: <unknown> is not a numpy array
```

Please anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: It seems that you have installed OpenCV 2.3.x (not 2.4.0). Check the values reported by `cv2.__version__` and `cv2.getBuildInformation()`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer... At the end the problem was an incompatibility of the sample with the last version of the library...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution found: i replaced the following line in find_obj.py:

```
surf = cv2.SURF(1000)
kp1, desc1 = surf.detect(img1, None, False)
kp2, desc2 = surf.detect(img2, None, False)
desc1.shape = (-1, surf.descriptorSize())
desc2.shape = (-1, surf.descriptorSize())
```

with those:

```
surf_det = cv2.FeatureDetector_create("SURF")
surf_ext = cv2.DescriptorExtractor_create("SURF")
kp1 = surf_det.detect(img1)
kp2 = surf_det.detect(img2)
kp1, desc1 = surf_ext.compute(img1, kp1)
kp2, desc2 = surf_ext.compute(img2, kp2)
```

Hope this may help someone else... :D